# Connect GoAutoDial with Twilio Elastic SIP ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, twilio

We have a goautodial instance in ec2, we opened all inbound related ports to the rest of the world

Problem:

We can't connect to server, even zoiper can't connect to it, but on my local I can...

Comment: You are going to need to share a lot more info if any of us are going to be able to help. Additionally it sounds like your question is more server related at this point. Perhaps your question would get more feedback on ServerFault. http://serverfault.com/

Comment: well goautodial has default agents, locally I can connect every single default agents to zoiper, but after uploading it to ec2 the registration always fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened all ports, to specific IP's only, instead of blocking some ports to the world...